# How can we solve this limit: $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, limsup-and-liminf

The limit was $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\tan\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$
I tried several ways to solved it, but I didn't find the answer. I think that it doesn't have a limit, but I want to see others' opinions. What do you think? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your reason for beliving it doesn't have a limit?

Comment: What are the "several ways" that you have tried?

Comment: @Spencer Hey Thanks for your comment, well when I tried several techniques That I know, I failed. So I end up drawing the function tanx/x and as you know the curve is repeatable, so we can't guess the limit. That's why :)

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I tried to change the variable, then put the tanx as sinx/cosx but no result at the end, so I thought maybe we can solve it by the euler expression and use the commun exp limits we know, but no result too always undefind, and L'hopital rules didn't help too :)

Comment: @AmineMarzouki, thats good; now consider $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} (sin(x)/x)$, does that exist? Whats the difference from your example?

Comment: @Spencer Well, yes I found in many websites, that's equals to 0, but I need how did they found it.

Answer (score 4):

The limit does not exist. Here is a way to prove it.

You have, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\tan\left(2n\pi\right)}{2n\pi}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{0}{2n\pi}\right)=0.
$$
You also have, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$
\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\tan\left((2n+1)\frac{\pi}2-\frac1n\right)}{(2n+1)\frac{\pi}2-\frac1n}\right)=\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\frac{\cos(1/n)}{((2n+1)\frac{\pi}2-\frac1n)\sin(1/n)}\right)=\frac1{\pi}\neq 0.
$$

Comment: Good Idea thanks for your answer, however I didn't understand the last one, why does $\left(\left(2n+1\right)\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin \left(1/n\right) = \pi $ ?

Comment: @AmineMarzouki You may recall that, as $n \to \infty$, we have $\sin(1/n) \sim 1/n$. Thanks!

Comment: Still didn't understand it. we have n -> inf so lim as n approach infinity of 1/n  is 0 then sin(0)=0. Where did I miss ?

Comment: @Armine Marzouki. As $n \to \infty$, you have $$\left(\left(2n+1\right)\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\sin \left(\frac1n\right) \sim \left(\left(2n+1\right)\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{1}{n}\right)\frac1n = \frac{2n}{n}\frac{\pi}2+O \left(\frac1n\right) \to \pi.$$

Comment: No that's not what I didn't understand, my problem is why that sin(1/n) = 1/n ?

Comment: Ok, by the Taylor expansion, you have, as $x \to 0$, $\sin x \sim x$. Here $x=1/n$. Tell me if it is Ok.

Comment: Still I miss something here, as far as I know $\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\frac{sin\left(x\right)}{x}\right)$ = 1 right? so where did you come with 1/n ? and what that symbol means ~ ?

Comment: In fact, as $x \to 0$, $\sin x \sim x$ means that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$. Observe that this last equality may be rewritten as $\frac{\sin x}{x}=1+e(x)$, with $e(x) \to 0$, thus $\sin x=x+x \times e(x)$.

Comment: Did you use euler expression here ? sinx = 1/2i (e(ix)-e(-ix))

Comment: Sorry mate If I take too much time on this, but why sinx/x  = 1+ e(x)

Comment: I think e(x) in this case is not exponentiel right?

Comment: Right, just a function tending to $0$ as $x$ tends to $0$. I could have call it $\epsilon(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

As I see from your comments, you are in the right way. However, you need to prove it mathematically.

HINT: Try to find a sequence $\{a_n\}$ increasing to infinity such that $\{f(a_n)\}$ diverges.

[As you show your work by editing the original post I will keep adding small hints if needed.]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you clarify more your idea? How can we solve a limit with sequences ? can you provide an example ?

Comment: My idea is precisely what the user Olivier Oloa wrote in his answer (however, I did not want to do the whole thing since it looks like a homework exercise). Essentially, the idea is to prove that the function is not arbitrarily close to any value whenever $x\to \infty$, which contradicts the definition of limit, and therefore is sufficient to prove its unexistence. Let me show you a simpler example: If $f(x)=1$ in $[2k,2k+1)$ ($k\in \Bbb N$), and $0$ elsewhere, then $f(2k)=1$ and $f(2k+1)=0$ for all $k$, so the function cannot have any limit.

Comment: Yep That makes sense now Thank you !

Comment: You're welcome :).